# fputcsv unexpected behavior

Tags: php, export-to-csv, fputcsv

Take a look at this code example:

```
$store = array('This is something \" "special"!', 'Something else "special"!');
$ff = fopen('/tmp/aaaa.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($ff, $store);
fclose($ff);
```

It gives as a result this:

```
"This is something \" ""special""!","Something else ""special""!"
```

What bothers me is that \" remains unchanged. I would expect it to become \"" or at least "". Am I wrong?

In any case this behavior breaks the csv since, for example, postgresql refuses to import such csv...

Comment: To clarify further I use Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and PHP 5.5.9

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php do you see the extra parameters you can add ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*fputcsv* function by default escapes the backslash character. You can check in the manual [$escape_char = "\"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

If you don't want to escape the backslash character then you can specify other character like below:

```
fputcsv($ff, $store, ',', '"', '!');
```

This will give you the desired output.

Comment: Unfirtunately I need this to work in Php 5.4 as well. Fputcsv does not have that param in those versions...

Comment: I will accept this as an answer since no other solution is available for older php versions other than writing custom fputcsv.